# Read Excel file in android

Tags: android, excel

Im developing an android App I want to read the data in from Excel File Anyone having Idea How to read Excel file in android. I keep my file in `res/raw` folder and try to read it as given in this tutorial http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaExcel/article.html Its not working if anyone having Idea then Reply Please

Thank you

Abhishek

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/)

Also, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919531/how-to-open-excel-sheet-in-android)

Comment: There are so many related questions about how to read excel file in android but no proper answer

Comment: Using Apache POI in android the eclipse fails to generate apk.And gives error : conversion to dalvik format failed with error 2. Too many methods: 66024; max is 65536. Abhishek can you tell how did you to read excel(.xlsx) file.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out jexcelapi (http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/) or apache poi (http://poi.apache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Keep the file in the SDcard and give the path of the SDCArd while reading the file

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Excel/filename.xls");
```

For eg. if you are keeping the file in excel folder then give the path as above