# How to convert excel sheet into android sqlite database

Tags: android

i am converting excel sheet into sqlite database but i have no idea,how to convert it . How to convert excel sheet into android sqlite database .help me please . Thanks in advance .

Comment: you can find tutorials to fetch data from excel file using poi library
when you did that save that in database

Answer (score 1):

You can first read data from excel [How to open excel sheet in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5919531/how-to-open-excel-sheet-in-android) and then write values in `SQLiteDatabase`

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 practical options:

1. You can open the Excel file directly in the app, as Krrishnaaaa said,
2. You can convert the Excel to a SQLite file first, and then drop and read that SQLite file in the app.

   - This tool can convert the file file to SQLite for you - http://converttosqlite.com/

And one impractical option:

1. You can open the Excel file in the app, write the values to a new SQLite database straight on the phone, and then read in the values from the new SQLite DB.

   - This is obviously not as optimal as option #1 or #2, since you're unnecessarily converting the data at runtime - which could be slow.

**TLDR;**

If you want to convert Excel to SQLite and query the SQLite DB in your app , use option #2.

If you want to read an Excel file straight in your app, use option #1.